# First Production Sound Job in the Industry

Tags: production

Hey Fellow Sound Enthusiasts,

I just finished college and was able to score some gigs in Los Angeles for a Production Sound Company. It will be my first professional audio industry job. I was wondering if anyone had any great advice to help me succeed in this industry and things I should avoid doing or always should make sure to do.

Thanks,

***KRUX***

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is great advice but here's my 2 cents.

I reckon the one thing everyone appreciates is a person who's willing to learn unconditionally. Easier said than done, but if the willingness is there, then we'll all be more inclined to help and teach you.

Be alert and aware of whats going on, don't just stand around and wait for someone to tell you to do something, ask if you can help. Good help is always appreciated and if you can learn to fill in the gaps and pick up the pieces that have fallen over, then you will be proving your value. In fact, be a sponge and observe what goes on. You are in a privileged position, so make sure you absorbed all that you can.

Learn fast and well. It's okay to make mistakes but clarify what you don't understand with your colleagues so that it doesn't happen again.

Everything boils down to attitude and personality so try to psych yourself up for the day's work. Be an Energizer bunny and annoy everyone with your enthusiasm and positive attitude.

Laugh. :D